# Losing Pointer To Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

Why might the thread pointer disappear?
As you see in the output. The 'obj' key gets deleted

```
def handle_threads(self):
    threads = 0
    for key, value in self.work_order.todo_list.items():
        print value
        if value['obj'].is_alive():
            threads += 1
        elif value['obj'].result == True:
            del self.work_order.todo_list[key]
    print threads
    if threads:
        sublime.set_timeout(lambda: self.handle_threads(), 100)
```

Output:

```
{'obj': <Main(Thread-93, stopped 4508)>, 'order': 'string1'}
{'obj': <Main(Thread-94, started 5704)>, 'order': 'string2'}
{'order': 'string2'}
```

Comment: It's very unlikely resulting from this code. You should find another source of the issue. BTW, changing a iterated dictionary on the fly is incorrect operation which can result in spoiled key order.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're deleting the (key,value) pair of key `'obj'` in this line of code:

```
del self.work_order.todo_list[key]
```

For example:

```
d = {'example':'hello','example2':'goodbye'}
print(d)

>>>> {'example':'hello','example2':'goodbye'}

del(d['example'])

>>>> {'example2':'goodbye'}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but if you wanted to keep the key but get rid of the value. Use:

```
self.work_order.todo_list[key] = None
```